# Openshift rhc ssh IO error after env set JAVA_OPTS_EXTcommand

Tags: ssh, openshift

I've run into an issue with openshift - after setting the environment variable over rhc env set JAVA_OPTS_EXT=" -D spring.profile.active=production" my ssh access broke down giving me weird access rights error. Some ideas here?
[image]

Comment: I tried re- rhc setup-ing as described here, http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/permission-denied-openshift-ssh/, however still the same behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for what reason after setting a different value onto the JAVA_OPTS_EXT it locked me out of permissions. It was sufficient to unset the variable and set it again to a desired value. Everything started to work smoothly again afterwards.

A command to unset the environment variable: "rhc env unset {VARIABLE1} -a {APP_NAME}"

A command to set the environment variable: "rhc env set {VARIABLE1}={VALUE1} -a {APP_NAME}"

For further info about the manipulation of environmnet variables refer to https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html